# How do I turn off the daylight cycle Minecraft 1.5.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to turn off daylight cycle and it's not working. The commands I have used are `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false`, `/daylock true` and `/gamerule allwaysday true`.

Answer (score 1):

You already gave the correct answer:

```
 /gamerule doDaylightCycle false
```

Except it doesn't work before 1.6.1.
You would need (to create) a mod to do so if you want to stop time before that version.

Pressing F6 might (still) reverse time in that version, but I am not holding out hope. If it does, creating an automated script to press F6 once in a while could work.